# what means "The matching wildcard is strict"

Tags: xml, xsd

> Validating the XML against the
>   Controlling Documents   ERROR:
>   cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching
>   wildcard is strict, but no declaration
>   can be found for element
>   'adlcp:datafromlms'. line: 21, col: 24

here is error line in  my xml file:

```
< adlcp:datafromlms>course=e7.txt;lesson=1< /adlcp:datafromlms>
```

this is from XSD:

```
  <xs:element name = "dataFromLMS" type = "dataFromLMSType"/>
  < xs:simpleType name = "dataFromLMSType">
     <xs:restriction base = "xs:string"/>
  < /xs:simpleType>
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, it should be dataFromLMS  OF COURSE

closing..